# Change Keyboard Background Color

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to set a different background color for the keyboard to increase the contrast between the view and keyboard. I have looked at several tutorials but could not able to find anything which is related to that issue.

In the following figure, keyboard background color is light gray but I want it to be black.

[image]

Comment: That is a setting on the users device, not of your application. Your only bet would be creating a whole new keyboard for your app which is possible: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Comment: You need a custom keyboard.